# Including pdf as appendix without shift of page

Tags: pdfpages

When I try to include a pdf file in my appendices, it gives the header and the label, and begins the pdf-file on the next page. I have a lot of pdf-files as my appendices, many only 1 page long, meaning I will have a lot of blank pages only saying:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Interviews}
\subsection{Interview: Christine}
\includepdf[pages=1-2]{fig/interviews/christine.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

This results in:

[image]

The rest of the page is then blank, and the actual appendix begins on the next page.

Is there any way I can alter the pdf-file to begin on the same page as the headline, maybe by scaling it to be smaller than actual page-sizes, so it fits on the same page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If a box (like the included pdf page) does not fit the page, it will be moved to the next one. Have a look at the [`pdfpages` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) regarding the options of `\includepdf`. The option `templatesize` might allow you to shrink the page (didn't try it, though).

Comment: You can include your `pdf` as an image using `\includegraphics{fig/interviews/christine.pdf}`. You can then use options like `\includegraphics[height=<some-dimension>]{<PATH>}` to ensure your `pdf` fits the rest of the page. However, it's text (i.e. font size) will be shrunck/inconsistent with the rest of the document.